# graphic cards for PCMCIA slots

Tags: graphics-card, lenovo-laptop, hardware-acceleration, pcmcia

I have a "lenovo 3000 c200" notebook.
I want to use a graphic card accelerator.
I wonder if exists a PC Card (PCMCIA) graphic accelerator like NVidia GeForce or ATI Radeon.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it's an [ExpressCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressCard) then there is connectivity for PCI-E x1. You could in theory therefore take something like this [PCI-E x1 9500GT](http://www.club-3d.com/index.php/products/reader.en/product/121.html) card a make a homebrew adapter for it. (Or even use x8/x16 card with it: [like this guy did](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/249291-12-card)). Slightly risky proposition really and I'm not sure it's worth it, but it might be a fun project and you'd probably get a slashdot story out of it.

Comment: There are commercial adapters available, no need to roll your own.  (see: http://www.villageinstruments.com/tiki-index.php?page=ViDock).  And this isn't really THAT uncommon.

Comment: And actually, there used to be similar products for PCMCIA (although much more limited in performance, obviously!)

Comment: @Shinrai nice! I couldn't find any when I looked around earlier despite being pretty sure such things must exist

Comment: Well, PCMCIA is **old**. It is similar to the ISA bus on a 8086 IBM XT. Graphics cards from that era did about 320x200. If you want to use an old bus and expect modern performance then you might be disappointed.